# html2canvas and jsPDF, promise error, createObjectURL is not a Function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm working a piece of functionality that takes content from a Bootstrap modal, saves it to a PDF and downloads the file to my local PC.

Here's an excerpt from my HTML and listItem.js file

```js
function downloadPDF() {
  // some stuff

  html2canvas($("#printItems")[0], {
    allowTaint: true
  }).then(function(canvas) {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg, 1.0');
    var pdf = jsPDF({
      unit: 'mm',
      format: 'a4',
      orientation: 'portrait'
    });

    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'jpeg', 15, 2);
    pdf.save('test.pdf');
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body" id="printItems">
  <div class="container" id="selectedItems"></div>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

The problem I'm having is when I hit `pdf.save('test.pdf')` the function fails and I get the following error:

> Uncaught(in promise) TypeError: l(...).createObjectURL is not a function

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Also, I'm working with version 1.5.3 of jsPDF and 1.1.4 of html2canvas

Comment: Which browser are you using? `createObjectURL` is supported in most modern ones: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#browser_compatibility

Comment: Also note that you're missing `</script>` tags, but I don't think this is causing your issue.

Comment: I'm using version 92.0.4515.107 of google Chrome and version 92.0.902.67 of MS Edge

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I was typing fast. You're right, that's not the cause of my issue.

Comment: It may be worth using newer versions of the libraries. jsPDF latest is 2.4.0 and html2canvas is 1.3.2

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm in an environment where our plugins and other software (open source, paid, etc...) has to be approved. Currently the versions I posted are the highest  versions approved.

Comment: In that case you need to get approval for the latest version. Aside from fixing the problem which actually results in making your code function properly, there will be countless security fixes, which should help you argue your case.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and seems working without any problem. check the versions that I used from CDN in the below snippet.

I think @Rory McCrossan is right about trying new versions.

```
<html>
<header>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.3.2/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</header>

<body>

    <div class="modal-body" id="printItems">
        <div class="container" id="selectedItems"> Some Text...</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function downloadPDF() {
            html2canvas($("#printItems")[0], {
                allowTaint: true
            }).then(function (canvas) {
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg, 1.0');
                var pdf = new jspdf.jsPDF({
                    unit: 'mm',
                    format: 'a4',
                    orientation: 'portrait'
                });

                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'jpeg', 15, 2);
                pdf.save('test.pdf');
            });
        }
        downloadPDF()
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay, so I must be doing something wrong.  I ended up getting the latest and greatest plugins for html2canvas and jspdf, but still having the same issue. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Try another browser like opera, if your chrome is managed by your organization may cause such issues. Try and let me know.

Comment: Okay so I tried, Edge and FireFox, but still got the same result. I'm at a total loss right now....this should work.  I have the latest version of both thml2canvas and jsPDF. Now I'm wondering if I need more than just the jspdf.umd.min.js file

Comment: Have you tried on your own laptop/pc instead of your organization's one? if not please try and let me know.

Comment: It has to be the organizations setup of our PCs. I tried this here on my home laptop and it worked perfectly fine.  Geesh.....well, I may have to find an alternative.

Comment: Ok, i think it's security issue, it's hard to explain but it goes around that your browsers can't access the filesystem regarding some restrictions that have been made by your organization's IT Team, that's my guess because i had such issues. I told you to use Opera, did you try it? Opera saved my life once when i was facing issue like this.

Comment: I think finding an alternative solution won't solve your problem.

Comment: Opera is not available to me on our network. So I built a quick app outside the code base of the sandbox site. To confirm if there was an issue with the browser or the organizations STIGs on our network. Well, the damn thing worked. So I guess now I have to figure out what's going on in my script file or in my html that's breaking this save functionality. I even changed my function for canvas into a arrow function, same result.

Answer (score 0):

This was a very strange issue, but I figured out what was wrong and it really had nothing to do with the jspdf or html2canvas versions I was using.  For some reason jspdf did not like me referencing a URL in two of my other scripts. Once I removed the actual URLs(https) and just had the physical path it worked fine. I was going down the wrong road looking into versioning and figuring out different ways to write a promise. LOL and SMH

The code I posted above works now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).